# Cascading a remote WMTS with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wmts

Since version 2.12.x GeoServer has the ability to proxy a remote Web Map Tile Service (WMTS). Is it possible to publish the remote WMTS as a WMTS on my GeoServer? If yes, how can I realize it in Geoserver?

One use case for cascading the WMTS is to hide the api_key of the remote WMTS request URL.

Answer (score 2):

You add the remote wmts as a datastore by providing a link to the getcapabilities document.

The layers are then available as WMS and WMTS layers in your geoserver as normal.